# GeoServer-2.21.4-winsetup.exe build for Windows is not available

Tags: geoserver, windows

GeoServer-2.21.4-winsetup.exe build for Windows is not available.

Link from official maintain branche:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/geoserver/files/GeoServer/2.21.4/GeoServer-2.21.4-winsetup.exe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GeoServer project has right now an issue with a certificate that is needed for creating a trusted Windows installer. From a geoserver-users mailing list https://sourceforge.net/p/geoserver/mailman/message/37782661/

> In addition the OSGeo certificate used to sign the windows installer
> is stalled during its renewal process - so we do not have a windows
> installer to share for recent releases :(

Answer (score 2):

Do yourself a favor and use the occasion to switch to a set-up better suited for production: get the Tomcat 9 installer, make it run as a service, deploy the geoserver.war file into it.

Make sure you make a backup copy of your data directory before starting the process.

Comment: Agree with this solution, it's the best scenario for deployment on Windows. We will try to change it in the near future.